# Collecting values from parameters passed from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When i submit my form I am getting the following parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3434343445=", "form"=>{"requested_user"=>"user@example.com"}, "form_type"=>"repository_creator", "gitcategory"=>{"name"=>"mechanical"}, "svncategory"=>{"name"=>"sales"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

In my model `self.requested_user` is available for me as the `requested_use`r is a field in my form for the model. But the other values like `svncategory` and `gitcategory` are passed from a select tag which is not stored in my database and not a part of my model as well. I am passing that just by html dropdown list as I don't want to store it anywhere.

*How do i access that variables i.e, `svncategory's name` and `svncategory's` name in my model.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters passed to your controller is available through the variable `params`. `params[:svncategory].inspect` would result in `{"name"=>"sales"}`.

The `params` variable is only accessible through the controller layer, so you'd have to pass the parameters needed along to the model.

One could sove this by adding attr_acccessors to your model.

```rb
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :gitcategory, :svncategory
end
```

and then set the attributes manually when instantiating a object.

```rb
your_model = YourModel.new(params[:form])
your_model.gitcategory = params[:gitcategory][:name]
your_model.svncategory = params[:svncategory][:name]
```

although it isn't an ideal solution, it solves your problem.